# How to sort the list A in an increasing order, such that I can modify the other list B with change in element position of list A

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, sorting

I have two lists A and B, I am trying to change modify the elements of list A in an increasing order such that my list B should also be changed according to list A. The node no list is given below. [image: expected out put]

```
nodeno = {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,  19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 2, 33, 34, 35,     36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52,
    53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68,     69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85,
    86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 32, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101,     102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114,     115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 92};

A = {0.0000, 0.33333*^-001, 0.66667*^-001, 0.10000, 0.13333, 0.16667, 
   0.20000, 0.23333, 0.26667, 0.30000, 0.33333, 0.36667, 0.40000, 
   0.43333, 0.46667, 0.50000, 0.53333, 0.56667, 0.60000, 0.63333, 
   0.66667, 0.70000, 0.73333, 0.76667, 0.80000, 0.83333, 0.86667, 
   0.90000, 0.93333, 0.96667, 1.0000, 1.0333, 1.0667, 1.1000, 1.1333, 
   1.1667, 1.2000, 1.2333, 1.2667, 1.3000, 1.3333, 1.3667, 1.4000, 
   1.4333, 1.4667, 1.5000, 1.5333, 1.5667, 1.6000, 1.6333, 1.6667, 
   1.7000, 1.7333, 1.7667, 1.8000, 1.8333, 1.8667, 1.9000, 1.9333, 
   1.9667, 2.0000, 2.0333, 2.0667, 2.1000, 2.1333, 2.1667, 2.2000, 
   2.2333, 2.2667, 2.3000, 2.3333, 2.3667, 2.4000, 2.4333, 2.4667, 
   2.5000, 2.5333, 2.5667, 2.6000, 2.6333, 2.6667, 2.7000, 2.7333, 
   2.7667, 2.8000, 2.8333, 2.8667, 2.9000, 2.9333, 2.9667, 3.0000, 
   3.0333, 3.0667, 3.1000, 3.1333, 3.1667, 3.2000, 3.2333, 3.2667, 
   3.3000, 3.3333, 3.3667, 3.4000, 3.4333, 3.4667, 3.5000, 3.5333, 
   3.5667, 3.6000, 3.6333, 3.6667, 3.7000, 3.7333, 3.7667, 3.8000, 
   3.8333, 3.8667, 3.9000, 3.9333, 3.9667, 4.0000};

B = {0., 0.00667455, -0.000127735, -0.000253022, -0.000373416, \
-0.00048648, -0.000589791, -0.000680937, -0.000757529, -0.000817198, \
-0.000857599, -0.000876413, -0.000871348, -0.000840142, -0.000780558, \
-0.000690389, -0.000567452, -0.000409589, -0.00021466, 0.0000194606, 
   0.000294888, 0.000613737, 0.000978126, 0.00139019, 0.0018521, 
   0.00236604, 0.00293428, 0.00355913, 0.00424301, 0.00498843, 
   0.00579801, 0.00667455, 0.00806478, 0.0101464, 0.0128567, 
   0.0161336, 0.019915, 0.0241395, 0.0287463, 0.033675, 0.0388665, 
   0.0442623, 0.0498052, 0.0554396, 0.0611109, 0.0667666, 0.0723559, 
   0.0778301, 0.0831425, 0.0882489, 0.0931078, 0.0976802, 0.10193, 
   0.105824, 0.109332, 0.112428, 0.115087, 0.117291, 0.119022, 
   0.120268, 0.121019, 0.12127, 0.121019, 0.120268, 0.119022, 
   0.117291, 0.115087, 0.112428, 0.109332, 0.105824, 0.10193, 
   0.0976802, 0.0931078, 0.0882489, 0.0831425, 0.0778301, 0.0723559, 
   0.0667666, 0.0611109, 0.0554396, 0.0498052, 0.0442623, 0.0388665, 
   0.033675, 0.0287463, 0.0241395, 0.019915, 0.0161336, 0.0128567, 
   0.0101464, 0.00806478, 0., 0.00579801, 0.00498843, 0.00424301, 
   0.00355913, 0.00293428, 0.00236604, 0.0018521, 0.00139019, 
   0.000978126, 0.000613737, 0.000294888, 
   0.0000194606, -0.00021466, -0.000409589, -0.000567452, \
-0.000690389, -0.000780558, -0.000840142, -0.000871348, -0.000876413, \
-0.000857599, -0.000817198, -0.000757529, -0.000680937, -0.000589791, \
-0.00048648, -0.000373416, -0.000253022, -0.000127735};

With[{p = Ordering[ansysxaxis]}, A = A[[p]]; B = B[[p]];]

data = Transpose[{A, B}]
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]
```

Comment: With `A`,  `B` and `nodeno` from your edit, try `ListPlot[Transpose[{A, B[[nodeno]]}], Joined -> True]`

Comment: worked thanks. I was sorting the wrong variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
o = Ordering @ A;
data1 = Transpose[{A[[o]], B[[o]]}];
```

Alternatively,

```
data2 = SortBy[First] @ Transpose[{A, B}];

data1 == data2
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
ListPlot[data1, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I am also getting the same result,  but the results of the Ansys software is smooth and there is no jump at x=3

Comment: @acoustics So maybe Ansys is not doing what you believe it is. In any case, this answers your OP.

Comment: still not working, you can verify this by plotting  before and after applying sorting

Comment: @acoustics can you clarify what or how this is “not working”?

Comment: I have added expected out put in the OP. Given x coordinate, I am trying to plot the  y values